# Build Custom SSO with SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, identity, saml-2.0

**Updated:** Thanks for responding on my post. I am very sorry, as of today these were the requirement details. However, I can elaborate more on what I understand. I some idea on WIF, where I can write my own STS, RP and publish policies.

Couple of queries here. Do we need to have an IdP and should we connect STS to IdP. if not, can we go without IdP. I will have to use claim base authentication and federated identity mgmt in the application.we do not depend on AD/LDAP integration.

Imp Requirements are in this way. 1) we allow customers to do self registration who are direct users of this portal-M and the other set of users come from partner-X where the company claims are verified using SAML Req/Resp to access the portal-M. 2) once the direct user or user-thru-partner-X enters the portal-M, he/she should get access to another portal-N of partner-Y sending SAML request in similar fashion.

I have provided as much as details I know, since I am new to this technology of SSO/FIdM

I would happy to provide more information, if needed

**Original**
I have got a complex task to build a solution of externalized SSO with SAML that would be used by customers of different partners over web. the constraints are to build IdP/STS/Issuers/RP/Trusts/Policies with no open source or commercial product support choosing specific technology platforms such as Microsft or/and J2EE.

On top of these, IdP must have to use in house custom data store available on SQL Server and Oracle.

your ideas are appreciable and thanks in advance

Comment: I do SAML all the time and would love to help, but this question is way too broad.  Can you edit it to state everything you *already* know, and try to come up with a specific question that you want help with?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to implement a SAML stack without using any commercial or open source software?

That is a HUGE amount of work and you will need to spend a non-trivial amount of time getting your head around SAML.

In terms of a DB as your Identity repository, refer: [Thinktecture IdentityServer](https://github.com/thinktecture).

In terms of SAML stacks, refer: [SAML : A SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html) .

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I want to build custom STS and integrate with ADFS (which is available in house). I would like to understand can we integrate a custom data store into ADFS and use it with custom STS registered in ADFS.

Comment: Do you mean "custom data store" with ADFS for authentication or for authorization? ADFS can only authenticate against AD. You can federate your custom STS with ADFS but you could do this with the WS-Federation protocol? Why does it have to be SAML?

Comment: I read few articles today and found ADFS can be configured to use custom identity store. let me know your thoughts on this link with respect to my query. thanks for your help http://blogs.technet.com/b/vinitt/archive/2013/04/15/how-to-use-to-custom-sql-attribute-store-to-generate-claims-and-authorize-user.aspx

Comment: Yes but you can only use that store for authorization not authentication.

Comment: Can I implement federated identity management and SSO with WIF and supporting Microsoft technologies

Comment: Yes - WIF together with ADFS should get you started.

Comment: One last question, with the combination of WIF and ADFS can I connect to custom identity store hosted in Oracle or SQL Server. please help and guide me with a proper study material or web links. Thanks

Comment: Yes - just use IdentityServer (link above) - fully functional STS running on SQL Server. It's open source so you can modify as appropriate.