# Google Apps for Work Custom Login Page

Tags: google-api, google-apps

This is the required scenario:

1- User visits www.mypage.com

2- She sees our own custom login page, it contains text boxes for username and password, our logo and any other content we wish to display.

3- The user enters her Google username and Google password into the custom login page.

4- Once she submits, she's authenticated with Google and automatically redirected to her Gmail Inbox.

Is that achievable? if yes, what protocol or API should be used?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into implementing SSO to use with your Google Apps account. This is the only way to have the custom login page you're talking about here.

Beyond that, it sounds like you're specifically looking for an IdP-initiated environment where the SAML request starts with your IdP and goes to Google. There are some limitations here and I don't believe it's considered a best practice. You will need to discuss this with different IdPs are you look into this solution and see what they recommend.

Comment: Do you have any sample SSO implementations in C# or Java for example?

Comment: There are so many good IdPs and solutions around, I've never looked into creating one from scratch. To quote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538058/build-custom-sso-with-saml: "it's a HUGE amount of work."